# How to manage images in Gmail signatures centrally

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

We use Gmail for business.

We'd like the same image to appear in all staff email signatures.

From time to time, we need to change the image:

We'd like to be able to update the image once, centrally; and for it to update in people's signatures without each staff member needing to replace the image in their own signature.

Staff have other details in their signatures also – details individual to them, such as their name.

Is there a way to manage the signature image centrally?

For example to host it somewhere, and add some code into Gmail signatures?

If yes, what code would do the trick?